# ORM not working in Default UserController & User Model in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, relationship

I want to get User wise Role. here is I'm facing error ....

UserController.php ( user controller file )

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use App\Employee;
use App\Role;
use App\User;
use App\Site;
use App\Client;
use App\ProjectType;
use App\UserPermission;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Project;

class UsersController extends BaseController {

public function __construct() {
    $this->isSetClientAndProjectType();

    $data = User::with('Role')->first();        
    echo "<pre>";print_r(json_decode($data)); die;

    }
}
```

User.php ( user model file )

```php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable {

use SoftDeletes;

 use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'role_id', 'password', 'siteid', 'email', 'status', 'allowed_to_bypass_pm', 'allowed_to_bypass_admin'
];
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

// Get users roles
public function Role() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Role', 'role_id', 'id');
 }
}
```

Error is

[image]

How can i solve this error?

Help me guys.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If a user has many "roles" it should be `public function roles()`.

**You have defined:**

A single user has a role_id

**Therefore you need:**

If a user has a single role it would be:

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

The reverse on the Role model would be:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Since many users can have the same role.

Hope this helps.

Comment: user have single role

Comment: Do you have a `Role` model?

Comment: Literally just copy and paste the role() function I wrote or the answer from @rkj you don't need to add a foreign_key and local key. Literally `return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');` OR `return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);` Make sure it's a lowercase R for role for the function name and job done.

Comment: `namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
  use DB;

   class Role extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'role_name'
    ];

 }` this is my role model

Comment: Define the reverse on roles cause you'll probably need that later. i.e selecting all the users with a given role. Read the comment above yours @vijayChauhan

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `belongsTo` relationship

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable {

 use SoftDeletes, Notifiable;

 protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'role_id', 'password', 'siteid', 'email', 'status', 'allowed_to_bypass_pm', 'allowed_to_bypass_admin'
 ];

 protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
 ];

 // Get user's role
 public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
 }
}
```

Now fetch data

```
$user = User::with('role')->find(1);
$role = $user->role;
```

Comment: if you have `role_id` in `users` table and an `id` in `roles` table then `belongsTo` work sure. Just try, copy and paste my code

Comment: https://ibb.co/bu8gUd (database - role table link)
https://ibb.co/nzF6vJ (database - user table link)

Comment: everything looks good. did you replace the changes  in `User` model ?

Comment: nope, paste you all code. again same error brother.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173402/discussion-between-rkj-and-vijay-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your table structure and foreign key references are compatible with the model relationship methods used.

For example, you have used "HasMany" relationship on User model. For that, you will have to make sure that each record/row in users table(User model) "has many" associated records/rows in roles table(Role model).

Here HasMany method assumes a foreign key "role_id" on roles table(Role Model). On not finding of which, it throws error.

You first need to take in consideration the table structure of roles and users table(User and Role model) as per your requirement, and than add model relationship methods accordingly.

It can be a bit tricky if you are using the methods for the first time, you can refer the laravel documentation for the same:

[eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)